# install plugins for rabbitmq cluster

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a cluster with three rabbitmq instance, sometimes I need to install some plugins to acquired addition feature.
It seems that it need to manually install the same plugins for each rabbitmq.

The question is.

Is there any simple way to install plugins for cluster? installing plugins for each instance is error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no a way to do that.

you should use some tools like puppet or chef to setup the machines.